# How to count imported users into database when query runs for each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It's not simple count of inserted rows into database. I'm running one query for each user, so it's not like I import 5 users at once with one query. It would be easy then and I would use `affected_rows` or `num_rows`. But with the code like this:

```
do {

    if ($data[0]) {
    //var_dump($data);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$tabela` (";
    $last = end($anotherArray);
    $numberOfValues=count($anotherArray);
    if($numberOfValues==1){
        $query.="$anotherArray[0])";
    }else {
    foreach ($anotherArray as $something) {

    if ($something != $last) {
        $query .= "" . $something . ",";
        } else {
        $query .= "" . $something . ")";
        }
        }
        }

        $query .= "VALUES (";

        $lengtara = count($anotherArray);

        $length1 = count($data);

        foreach ($data as $d) {
                $query .= "'$d',";
                }

        $query = rtrim($query, ',');
        $query .= ")";
        $rez = $mysqli->query($query);
        $users_cnt=$mysqli->affected_rows;

        }
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
```

when I run `var_dump($users_cnt)` and lets say I inserted 3 new users, it shows `NULL`, `NULL`, `NULL`. But it's not some array that I could take `count` of. As you can see I'm, building query because it's structure depends on some dynamic data, and this is only way that works when it comes to inserting users. Please help if you have some suggestions.

Comment: Can't you declare variable in php above do loop with value of 0, once you do insert in table, just set that variable +1 ... at the end of loop, that variable will have count that you asking for?

Comment: Thanks man. It was obvious. My brain is a bit lagging this morning :)

Comment: Happens to everyone once in a while :) good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't do this:

```
$count = 0    
do {

        if ($data[0]) {

        //var_dump($data);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `$tabela` (";
        $last = end($anotherArray);
        $numberOfValues=count($anotherArray);
        if($numberOfValues==1){
            $query.="$anotherArray[0])";
        }else {
        foreach ($anotherArray as $something) {

        if ($something != $last) {
            $query .= "" . $something . ",";
            } else {
            $query .= "" . $something . ")";
            }
            }
            }

            $query .= "VALUES (";

            $lengtara = count($anotherArray);

            $length1 = count($data);

            foreach ($data as $d) {
                    $query .= "'$d',";
                    }

            $query = rtrim($query, ',');
            $query .= ")";
            $rez = $mysqli->query($query);
            $count++
            $users_cnt=$mysqli->affected_rows;

            }
            } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
```

Then just output `$count` wherever you need it.